# Windows Server 2022 Standard is giving me crashes in the HTTP module that reboot my server. I need help tracking down the exact issue. How?

Tags: windows, http, server-crashes, windows-server-2022, crash

I don't know if this is a problem with the memory on the server, one of my SSD's, or something software related. the crash has happened 4+ times in the last few months.

I need some help in figuring out how to stop this from happening ASAP. Any ideas?

Here is the stack trace:

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (7e)
This is a very common BugCheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff8029ea8ba7b, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: ffff928ac148b858, Exception Record Address
Arg4: ffff928ac148b070, Context Record Address


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Fault
    Value: Read

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3936

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 3841

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 17968

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 585841

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 130

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: fe_release_svc_prod2

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2022-07-07T18:32:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.20348.859


FILE_IN_CAB:  MEMORY.DMP

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1000

BUGCHECK_CODE:  7e

BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffffc0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8029ea8ba7b

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff928ac148b858

BUGCHECK_P4: ffff928ac148b070

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffff928ac148b858 -- (.exr 0xffff928ac148b858)
ExceptionAddress: fffff8029ea8ba7b (HTTP!UlpGetSendCacheDataSize+0x0000000000000017)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

CONTEXT:  ffff928ac148b070 -- (.cxr 0xffff928ac148b070)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffff80009068ed98 rcx=3a22707061222020
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=ffffc38e63d74840 rdi=ffffc38e6414b030
rip=fffff8029ea8ba7b rsp=ffff928ac148ba98 rbp=ffff928ac148bb20
 r8=0000000000000001  r9=00000000ffffffff r10=fffff80276af8d60
r11=ffff928ac148ba70 r12=0000000000000000 r13=ffffc38e6414b010
r14=ffffc38e63d748b0 r15=ffffc38e623aba80
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
HTTP!UlpGetSendCacheDataSize+0x17:
fffff802`9ea8ba7b 8b4128          mov     eax,dword ptr [rcx+28h] ds:002b:3a227070`61222048=????????
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

READ_ADDRESS:  ffffffffffffffff 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffffffffff

EXCEPTION_STR:  0xc0000005

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff928a`c148ba98 fffff802`9eb57402     : 00000000`00000001 ffffc38e`66bc0710 ffffc38e`646e6780 fffff802`76a3162f : HTTP!UlpGetSendCacheDataSize+0x17
ffff928a`c148baa0 fffff802`9eb2e012     : fffff802`9eb57301 fffff802`9eb33901 00000000`00000001 fffff802`9eb57380 : HTTP!UlSendCacheEntryWorker+0x82
ffff928a`c148bb60 fffff802`76b69f15     : ffffc38e`63d748b0 fffff802`9eafe580 00000000`00000480 00000000`00000000 : HTTP!UlpThreadPoolWorker+0x112
ffff928a`c148bbf0 fffff802`76c24488     : ffffad81`4ca40180 ffffc38e`646e6080 fffff802`76b69ec0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffff928a`c148bc40 00000000`00000000     : ffff928a`c148c000 ffff928a`c1486000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  HTTP!UlpGetSendCacheDataSize+17

MODULE_NAME: HTTP

IMAGE_NAME:  HTTP.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffff928ac148b070 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  17

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_HTTP!UlpGetSendCacheDataSize

OS_VERSION:  10.0.20348.859

BUILDLAB_STR:  fe_release_svc_prod2

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {640925e0-41aa-2deb-fe92-17674389e426}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly related to an update, you are by far not the only one having it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185893/windows-server-2022-standard-(21h2-20348-1547)-cra

IF I had to guess (I do not run a comparable ENV to test) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2015/ms15-034 is likely where to start

OR

Your system does NOT contain this patch, and the nature of the CVE https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-1635 this could indicate that someone is actively TRYING to exploit the system. The fact that others started getting the error *before* the Apr patch, tends to favor this theory.As does an access violation in a memory operation!

IF the update is present I would rollback and see if that assists (I would consider other mitigation if you can, and remember this is an RCE.)

If it IS present do packet capture of the affected system if feasible, and correlate actual traffic to the web server to instance of crash. Would not be the first patch to not fully get a bug leading to another variant, or lead to instability because of an incomplete patch. Take the results to MS and let them look it over to make sure the patch is sound.

Comment: I did see this earlier but it says the exploit is only up to Windows Server 2012 R2. I'm running 2022. I'm curious though if this is a new exploit, or a variant, like you mentioned, that is related to this.

Comment: Quite possible. It is the nature of vulnerability that once found, scour all related to it, because the fact it exists means someone coding it did not see the error potential of the code that was written  and there may be more (As a dev sometimes it is because we do not understand that there even IS intrinsic error potential in the tools/code) That is why I would try to get a traffic analysis, to see if this is being externally triggered, if so take it to MS support. IF not, it is likely application code, and nothing I could do but suggest review by you or vendor's dev.

Comment: I've turned off IIS Output Kernel Caching, and that stopped the crash, just like the MS article you mentioned said to do for that vulnerability. Clearly there is some new exploit that hasn't been fixed yet that is in Server 2022. Hopefully Microsoft fixes it ASAP. I imagine more and more sys admins will be reporting it.

Comment: I have seen a lot of this in my days, often exploits in the wild are found by observation of things in progress vs updates and alerts. However it sometimes comes down to attempts on a now patched exploit vector just causing noise and erratic but not overtly threatening behavior. In such case if it still causes service disruption it is DOS potential at least. Were I you, I would still try to get a packet capture for study, and if you find anything suspicious, malicious, or simply explainable, report to MS so they can research further.